# How to import data of missing addresses into OSM local TileServer?

Tags: ubuntu, gis, postgis, openstreetmap, tileserver-gl

How to import data of missing addresses into OSM local TileServer?

I am having local TileServer GL/OpenMapTiles on Ubuntu 20.04. Installed by this guidline: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/basemap-tileserver-gl-openmaptiles-ubuntu-22-04
Maps uploaded from geofabrik.de: https://download.geofabrik.de/russia/volga-fed-district.html

Many addresses of buildings are missing in the OSM map. But I have database with buildings addresses and their coordinates in the region of previously uploaded map.

How I can to import buildings addresses into OSM PostgreSQL database by their coordinates? I want to find missing addresses of buildings in the OSM map and import there missing addresses from the database with buildings addresses and their coordinates.

Comment: Are you a programmer or a user? this site is about programming, and so, if you are a programmer, you should give use more details on which part of the import you have difficulties. But as I read the question, you may just want to insert data into the OSM database, so not much about programming (and so, you should read the structure of features in OSM,, then just convert your data into OSM features and import them in OSM. or just share your database to OSM mappers, so that they will include in the official database